# Does time causes inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, inertia

As you know inertia is an behaviour of matter that objects resist change in their motion. If an object is at rest it will remain at rest and if an object is moving with a constant velocity it will continue to move in that same direction with the same velocity until acted upon by an unbalanced force. Change in motion means acceleration and acceleration takes time. So objects resist change in their motion (acceleration) because they take time to do so and hence have inertia. But what would happen if objects don't take time to accelerate or instaneously accelerate. Would they have inertia even after that? Does this mean time actually causes inertia (or makes feel us so)?

Answer (score 2):

Inertia is just mass (or I suppose a property of mass?). Changes in velocity take a finite amount of time because in Newton's second law $\dot v=F/m$, the mass $m$ is non-zero. Furthermore, the mass $m$ is constant and independent of the motion of the object relative to some reference point.

So no, time does not cause inertia.

Answer (score 2):

Causality in the way you are using it here is in the domain of philosophy.  Whether time causes inertia or not is beyond where physics will go.

What we can say is that we cannot define the concept of inertial without the concept of time.  Physics makes observations and predictions.  We observe positions changing over time, and find predictable patterns.

When you have taken calculus (if you have not already), you will be able to tie concepts like inertia to the *passage* of time (which we notate as $dt$, but can be thought of as an infinitesimally small amount of time passing).  With that concept, you will be able to show that, if you make predictions about how massful things will change position over time using this concept of inertia, you predict correctly.

Comment: If you haven't taken calculus, just be aware that deep questions like these can get very tricky to answer.  Non-calculus-based physics can lead you to some "it has to be this way, simply because $\Delta t$ cannot be zero.  Calculus based physics, while calling for some stranger math, lets you overcome many of those issues in the same way adding red paint to a pallet of blues and greens widens your options.  You get short notations like the $\dot v=F/m$ that BioPhysics mentions which are very profound, and point better in the direction of these philosophical answers.

Comment: I think in calculus dt denotes infinitesimally small time. But even though the time interval is infinitesimally small it is not zero (at least I think). It is just that for smaller and smaller time interval you get a more better and better approximation and as the time interval is infinitesimally small, the approximation is also infinitely good means accurate. Thus we indirectly achieve the accurate (infinitely good) result.

Comment: @BIDISHDAS Can you phrase your second to last sentence ("But what would happen if objects don't take time to accelerate or instantaneously accelerate") in those sorts of terms?  It sounds like you've got a good handle on infinitesimals, and I think the act of re-wording that part of the question may help point you in the right direction, or might point me in the right direction.  One quickly starts to rule out whole branches of mathematics as we exclude things the acceleration can be.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting at a very deep insight.  Time and inertia (mass) are intimately related, and massless particles like photons have neither.  Any massless particle becomes possessed with inertia and the passage of time when it is confined.  It's too much for a post like this, but read up on Photon in a Box and Photon Clock.  The YouTube channel PBS Spacetime has a pretty great video on it.

https://youtu.be/gSKzgpt4HBU